# iOS Deep Link from Widget when App closed?

Tags: ios, swift, widget, deep-linking

My widget has several links that the user can click, the link are set up as follows:

```
Link(destination: URL(string: "widget://start")!)
```

Now I am able to detect the press in the scene delegate with the following function:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    if let item = URLContexts.first {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(item.url.absoluteString, forKey: "URL")
        print(item.url)
        print(URLContexts)
    }
}
```

However, that doesn't work when the app is closed. I tried putting this block of code everywhere, scene delegate, app delegate, but I just can't find a solution on how to detect the tap when the app is closed.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Add this

```
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            if let item = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(item.url.absoluteString, forKey: "URL")
                print(item.url)
                print(URLContexts)
            }
        }
    }
```

For those, who use only AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        if let userActDic = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? [String: Any],
           let userActivity  = userActDic["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as? NSUserActivity {
            // Do with user activity
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a solution for those who only have AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wait a little before load url

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    ...Your code
    
    // Load the link, but set a timeout of X seconds to fix app crashing when loading deep link while app is NOT already running in the background.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        self.handleUniversalLink(url: url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you only use AppDelegate, try this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url] as? URL {
        print(url)
    }
    return true
}
```