# iOS Deep link callbacks not working when the app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I'm using a deep linking in my application and using this code in my `SceneDelegate` to segue to a view controller.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
  for context in URLContexts {
    print("url: \(context.url.absoluteURL)")
    print("scheme: \(context.url.scheme ?? "")")
    print("host: \(context.url.host ?? "")")
    print("path: \(context.url.path)")
    print("query: \(context.url.query ?? "")")
    print("components: \(context.url.pathComponents)")
  }
    window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "splashToCreateNewPassword", sender: nil)
}
```

It's working perfectly when app is already open in the background, but when user closes the app, it wont work. it just opens the first screen of the app.

Comment: Does this your answer?  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65641227/14733292

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get URL from this delegate `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)`

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first {
            if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
                window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "splashToCreateNewPassword", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

For those, who use only AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        if let userActDic = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? [String: Any],
           let userActivity  = userActDic["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as? NSUserActivity {
            // Do with user activity
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if I have only App Delegate?

Comment: @YaroslavDukal check updated answer

Comment: do you think it's better to put some delay on code block in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions so to give the app more time to load?

Comment: @YaroslavDukal yes if it's required

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. In iOS(flutter build) I solved this by adding "Content Available." The article is here: Apple Content Available Document. I am using OneSignal so in the api I added that field. Now even if the app is forced closed it awakes and deep links work. The complete Onesignal postman code is:

```
{
  "app_id": "1234",
  "included_segments": ["Test"],
  "content_available" : true,
  "contents": {
                "en": "Hi"
            },
            "data": {
                "dynamic_link": "https://google.com"
            },
            "headings": {
                "en": "Testing"
            }
}
```